# RangeError [BitFieldInvalid]: Invalid bitfield flag or number: Messages

Tags: javascript, error-handling, discord, discord.js

I can’t figure how to solve this error, can someone help me in detail since I’m trying to make a bot? I’m sorry if I’m dumb.. [Here is the message:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNemU.jpg)
⠀
⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Comment: Do not add errors / stack track etc as images. Please add them as a code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

`Messages` isn't a [valid intent](https://discord-api-types.dev/api/discord-api-types-v10/enum/GatewayIntentBits). Did you mean `GuildMessages`, `DirectMessages`, or `MessageContent`?